# Charting recomendations for Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm looking for a decent charting library to use with Delphi 2010.

We dont want to require additional framework be installed on client PCs, so would like to avoid toolkits that use .Net, Java or Flash.

The chart types we need are pretty straight forward (2D and 3D pie/donut, bar, line), but the customer wants to have attractive charts with translucency, rounded edges, etc.  Similar to what's available from [Dundas Charts](http://www.dundas.com/Components/Gallery/Flash/Chart/).

[TeeChart](http://www.steema.com/products/teechart/vcl/overview.html) seems like a natural choice and we looked at [TMS Advanced Charts](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advchart.asp), but they don't support the appearance the customer is asking for.

Comment: what does prevent you from using Dundas Charts? is it just to avoid .net installation?

Comment: Yes.  Cost is another factor.  Even if we did require the customer to install the .Net runtime, it would be awkward to use Dundas' .Net visual libraries from native Delphi.  If this could be made seamless, I would certainly consider them for a future project.  Just not this one.

Answer (score 4):

TeeChart is excellent, but you must read the documentation.  At least initially, I found it somewhat non-intuitive, contrary to the experience of M Schenkel.  The documentation is good and extensive, as TeeChart has been around a while.  For customization, TChart exposes `OnBeforeDrawChart` and `OnAfterDraw`, and so Windows GDI methods can be use to modify the appearance.  TChart can also do certain [extended](http://www.steema.com/products/teechart/gallery_ext.html) chart types, including a [donut](http://www.steema.com/img_products/gallery/tch/donut.html).

Comment: +1 I agree, TeeChart is great. Takes a little time to get used to it, but then it's very well designed IMHO.

Comment: Yes it is.  Unfortunately, it doesn't support the appearance the customer is asking for.  At least not in V8.  I've spoken to Steema, and they tell me the VCL components will have more visual features in V9.  We'll see.

Comment: Responding to your edit: I would be very happy to learn how to duplicate something like this using TeeChart.  http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/Charting/i/features/3DDoughnut.png

Comment: It ain't a donut, but the fundamental look and feel can be similar: http://www.steema.com/img_products/gallery/tch/PieWarm1019x776.jpg

Comment: Ok, TeeChart can do donuts.  Answer updated with links to the sample gallery.

Answer (score 2):

I have used both TeeChart and TMS Charts.  Both can be used without any additional deployments (i.e. ActiveX, dlls).  I tend to use TeeCharts more; it is a bit more "seasoned" product and a little more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look: http://www.kronsoft.home.ro , but it's a died project.

Comment: They look good and might be a good fit for just the pie chart requirement.  I'm wary about using a defunct library, though.  I've written to the author to see if they're still available and if they support donuts and exploding pie segments.

Comment: The author has a more recent link and demo.  http://www.kronstudio.home.ro/

Answer (score 0):

The Jedi library offers a pretty decent charting / graph component,

it's very understandable and offers pretty much of customizing

http://www.delphi-jedi.org/